# What inheritance strategy on Entity Framework should I use for my base class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, relational-database, normalization

I have a base class with properties:

```
Id, CreatedOn, LastModifiedOn, DeletedOn, IsDeleted
```

All of my concrete classes inherit from this base class. Should I have a separate table for the base class or should I just include those inherited properties on each concrete class's table?

I'm not really familiar with the database normalization and I was thinking if it's okay to have a repeating columns in this scenario.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the derived classes and other requirements. Choosing an inheritance strategy -- or even deciding whether to inherit al all -- can't be done based on this bit of information. Start reading [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) and make your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework will automatically "include" those properties for you. Meaning if you use Code First, EF will generate Db tables with those properties.

For example:

```
public class EntityBase
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { set; get; } = -1;

        private DateTime? createDate;

        public DateTime CreateDate
        {
            set
            {
                createDate = value;
            }
            get
            {
                if (createDate.HasValue)
                    return createDate.Value;
                else
                    return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        public DateTime? UpdateDate { set; get; }
        public DateTime? DeleteDate { set; get; }

        public bool IsDeleted { set; get; }


        public int CreatedBy { set; get; }

        public int? UpdatedBy { set; get; }

        public int? DeletedBy { set; get; }

    }
```

And let's say you have:

```
public class Test1 : EntityBase 
{
     [MaxLength(500)]
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The generated migration will look something like this:

```
   CreateTable(
            "dbo.Test1",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 500),
                    CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    UpdateDate = c.DateTime(),
                    DeleteDate = c.DateTime(),
                    IsDeleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    CreatedBy = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UpdatedBy = c.Int(),
                    DeletedBy = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

So the answer is **no**, you don't have to create a separate table for the base class.

Comment: You didn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing **schema-first**, your code will be (or should be) automatically generated so there is no benefit to these common properties unless you are doing some business logic in there (can't imagine why).  Have the generated class match the table. i.e. each have `ID`; `CreatedOn`; `LastModified` etc.   When code is automatically it generally makes sense to let it generate everything.

Handcrafted **code-first** may be a different story, as it is entirely possible for you to use a base class with these properties in mind.  Doing so with these particular properties offers little benefit other than leading to possible confusion as to which properties in a class exist in a corresponding table.

> Should I have a seperate table for the base class or should I just include those inherited properties on each concrete class's table?

I would probably put them in the same table because during write operations, you don't want to modify the core table and then update another just to modify `LastModifiedOn`.  Doing so is would always require **transactions** which may lead to unwanted **performance loss**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How about this scenario. BaseClass <- Person <- Patient and BaseClass <- Person <- Doctor. Person class has the firstname, lastname, etc properties. The first thing I did was to create a patient table and doctor table with all the properties in it as a column, since that's what the EF generated after the code-first approach. But I after I learned about the TPT/TPH/TPC inheritance strategy on EF, I was thinking if do I need to create a seperate table for the person class using the inheritance strategy.

Comment: I'm really confused on HOW or IF I NEED TO normalize my database while using code first approach with Entity Framework.

Comment: I might have a confusion with the base class columns if I seperate the person table from patient and doctor. Or maybe there's something wrong with my approach.

Comment: @LanceBendo That sounds like a new question one on _how_ rather than _should I_.  Consider asking on another StackExchange site specific to databases **and** design.  Asking here is arguably _too broad_.  You have to ask yourself, "Do I really need DB normalisation?".  It complicates things and your app may not require it. Wishing you well.